# Map between two Enums

Tags: java, enums

I have below 2 Enums, One is for type and another is for value.

```
public enum DifferentiatorType {

    @JsonProperty("differentiatorType")
    MARKETPLACE_ID("MarketplaceId");

    private final String value;
}

public enum DifferentiatorValue {

    VALUE_ONE("valueOne");
    VALUE_TWO("valueTwo");
    VALUE_THREE("valueThree");
    VALUE_FOUR("valueFour");

    private final String value;
}
```

Now the situation is ,i have a payload which holds both the field DifferentiatorType and DifferentiatorValue. I want to check if the type belongs to DifferentiatorType then go and check if the value is present there in DifferentiatorValue then only proceed farther. So basically i want to create a map between the 2 Enums .

PS: In future new object/item can be added to DifferentiatorType and in that case we have to create new Enum for that type of values accepted.

Here is the sample payload:

```
{\"referenceId\":\"B01-2776421-8482453\",\"preferenceType\":\"CREDITCARD\",\"differentiatorValue\":\"ABXWY75J\",\"customerId\":\"A37I50ASYHT\",\"differentiatorType\":\"MarketplaceId\"}
```

Comment: I'm interpreting the description multiple ways - can you add an example payload, along with the expected result?

Comment: @AndrewS : Added one sample payload. And the expectation is if type is MarketplaceID then it should goo and check DifferentiatorValue. If the value in payload belongs to the Enum then we will do an API call else we won do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Use [EnumMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumMap.html) and [EnumSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumSet.html) to hold all the relationships.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.EnumSet;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;

public class DifferentiatorMappings {
    private final Map<DifferentiatorType, Collection<?>> values;

    public DifferentiatorMappings() {
        Map<DifferentiatorType, Collection<?>> map =
            new EnumMap<>(DifferentiatorType.class);

        map.put(DifferentiatorType.MARKETPLACE_ID,
            Collections.unmodifiableCollection(
                EnumSet.allOf(DifferentiatorValue.class)));
        map.put(DifferentiatorType.ANOTHER_ID,
            Collections.unmodifiableCollection(
                EnumSet.allOf(AnotherValue.class)));

        values = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
    }

    public Collection<?> getValuesFor(DifferentiatorType type) {
        if (type == null) {
            return Collections.emptySet();
        }

        return values.getOrDefault(type, Collections.emptySet());
    }
}
```

Then you can use the returned values collection to check for a correct value:

```
DifferentiatorType type = payload.getDifferentiatorType();
Object value = payload.getDifferentiatorValue();

DifferentiatorMappings mappings = new DifferentiatorMappings();
if (mappings.getValuesFor(type).contains(value)) {
    // proceed
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me try this.